# How to get "Physical Path Credentials Logon Type" for site and application?

Tags: iis, powershell

I have an IIS 8 website setup with an application within.

Using Powershell how can I get the "Physical Path Credentials Logon Type" setting (defaults to ClearText) for both the main site and the application?

What I have tried,

Setup a specific user and non default "Logon Type" for each of the applications.

```
(get-item IIS:\Sites\MYSITE).physicalPath
(get-item IIS:\Sites\MYSITE).username
(get-item IIS:\Sites\MYSITE).password
```

get me exactly the values I would expect but there is no "Logon Type" property available.

```
(get-item IIS:\Sites\MYSITE).virtualDirectoryDefaults
```

Shows the path,physicalPath,username and password all blank and has "logonMethod" set as the default "ClearText".

```
(get-item IIS:\Sites\MYSITE).Collection[0].virtualDirectoryDefaults
```

and

```
(get-item IIS:\Sites\MYSITE).Collection[1].virtualDirectoryDefaults
```

both show the same, the path,physicalPath,username and password all blank and the "logonMethod" is set as the default "ClearText".

Reason I want this is to add a check to a script that ensures sites meet a "settings check list", where I have been able to map all the other settings from powershell.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to stray from the **WebAdministration** module and into **Microsoft.Web.Administration.ServerManager**

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName "Microsoft.Web.Administration, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL"
$iis = new-object Microsoft.Web.Administration.ServerManager
($iis.Sites | where { $_.name -eq "MYSITE" }).applications[1] | select -ExpandProperty VirtualDirectories | select LogonMethod
```

returns

```
ClearText
```

The applications[1] indicates the second application, applications[0] is the root application.

The **Add-Type** version is important to avoid loading the IIS-Express server instance.

FYI because you have to create an instance of the server any changes in IIS manager are not available until you recreate that object.

Answer (score 0):

I think you stumbled upon the answer already. There doesn't seem to be an explicit property for this because the given credentials are just used to override the normal thread credentials.

You can, however, check to see if the username or password are set and create a function like this

```
function Get-PhysicalLogonType ($site) {
  if($site.username -eq '' -and $site.password -eq '') {
    return 'PassThrough'
  }
  return 'SpecificUser'
}

# ... use it somewhere in your script
$site = (get-item IIS:\site\mysite)
Get-PhysicalLogonType $site
```

Answer (score 0):

The below return the physicalPath of the VirtualDirectory and the logonMethod, I'm confident it can be done in such a way that you can target a specific "Application Directory".

```
Get-Item IIS:\Sites\* | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Collection | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Collection | Select-Object -Property physicalPath,logonMethod
```